# about communication to EDC by RS232 in c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have to Send Data to EDC by RS232 in c#. 
First,send the request to the machine,and the machine will response  "Ack" and then response the 304 bytes data to my computer.

Here is the problem:
I send a request Message to the machine , but I only received two "ACk", I can't  receive the machine's response message(304 bytes data).

and here is the format about the EDC:

> "STX+Data+ETX+LRC"
>   STX :   char STX=(char)2;
>   ETX :   char ETX=(char)3;
>   DATA : 304 bytes;
>   LRC :   Exclusive-Or All Bytes Of Data & ETX (STX Not Include).
>   **use ASCII code**

here is my code:

```
private SerialPort comport;

char  stx = (char)0x02;
char  etx =(char)0x03 ;
string data = "F0";

public static Char Calculatelrc(string lrcstr)
{
     byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lrcstr);
     byte lrc = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
     {
         lrc ^= bytes[i];
     }

     return Convert.ToChar(lrc);
 }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comport = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8,StopBits.One);
    comport.DataReceived+= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(comport_DataReceived);
    if(!comport.IsOpen){

       comport.Open();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 302; i++)
    {
        data += " ";
    }

    char lrc = Calculatelrc(data + etx.ToString());
    string CodeStr = string.Format(stx + data + etx + lrc.ToString());
    byte[] ReqBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CodeStr);
    comport.Write(ReqBytes, 0, ReqBytes.Length);
}

private void comport_DataReceived(Object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{                                     
     byte[] comBuffer = new byte[304];
     int lengh = comport.Read(comBuffer, 0, 304);
     Array.Resize(ref comBuffer, lengh);        
 }
```

Comment: Please help me solving the problem. thanks!

Comment: So you are sending 302 space characters to whatever an EDC is, and it is supposed to do what? Is there an error message, exactly what is received back? What have you tried to diagnose the problem?

Comment: EDC is the Credit card machine.
I only received two "ack" character from Credit card machine.
I dont know why  the machine didn't send the data I want(304 bytes).

Comment: Neither do I. Have you tried sending this exact data to the EDC by some other means and confirming that it can respond to what you are sending? Do you have a protocol specification that confirms that what you are sending should result in 300+ bytes being sent back? So you work out 304 how? I count STX+302bytes+ETX+LRC as 305.

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks! barny!  @barny

Comment: What was the problem?